# Windows for ARM what APIs are available

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

What are the APIs that I can use to develop for Windows on ARM tablets. I know the Windows RT APIs are available but there are other Metro related API sets that are questionable. I want to make an application that can run on ARM and x86 platforms.

The main point of my confusions is I don't know what subset of the .NET framework is available.

Reference Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br211369

Comment: ... Shouldn't the entire thing be available (assuming you have the assemblies in place)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Metro API availability across arm, x86, and x64 is the same. Anything that is available in metro will be available on all platforms.